# CSS | Adding Space between items inside a form

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a form that is inside a flexbox card. The card has 2 sides, left and right. The left is a picture and the right is the actual inputs. I need space in between the different inputs. They are too cramped currently. I have tried making the form a flexbox and justify-content: space-around, space-between neither worked how I wanted.

I have tried adding margin and padding to the form and the elements, but there has to be a better way. I attached an image as well as the [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg3ne6rh/7/) to help you see my issue.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #ccf2f4;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card {
    width: 75vw;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #a4ebf3;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.card-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.card-left,
.card-right {
    padding: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-left">
        <img src="https://media.bleacherreport.com/f_auto,w_800,h_533,q_auto,c_fill/br-img-slides/004/431/800/ca7761a4360ae26cb69ee014607228b7_crop_exact.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-right">
        <form action="">
            <div class="name">
                <label for="name" placeholder="Name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="seat">
                <label for="seat">Select your seat</label>
                <select name="seat" id="seat">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="handicapped">
                <label for="handicap">Handicapped?</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Handicapped" />
            </div>
            <div class="wrestler">
                <label for="wrestler">Select for favorite superstar</label>
                <select name="wrestler" id="wrestler">
                    <option value="asaka">Asaka</option>
                    <option value="mcintyre">Drew Mcintyre</option>
                    <option value="zayne">Sami Zayne</option>
                    <option value="reigns">Roman Reigns</option>
                    <option value="flair">Charlotte Flair</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="submit">
                <button>Sign Up!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not the best with CSS as I mainly use JavaScript but I created a few projects to help me use CSS more and try and learn more and become a better all around dev. Thank you for your time and help.[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH92C.jpg)

Comment: You can put your fiddle here, in your question, as a stack snippet instead of a separate jsfiddle.

Comment: @StephenP thanks man, I barely use StackOverflow so I appreciate that

Comment: Why not just add some line-height to your 2nd card and add a little margin to the input elements to space things out a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is just some space between `input` elements, you can add the following to your css

```
.card-right div{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

since you already have each `input` element in a `div` of its own, this will work well.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: .9em;
  background-color: #ccf2f4;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 75vw;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #a4ebf3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card-right div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card-left,
.card-right {
  padding: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple Form Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Wrestlemania 36 Sign Up!</h1>
    <h2>Use the form below to reserve your spot for the year's biggest event</h2>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-left">
        <img src="https://media.bleacherreport.com/f_auto,w_800,h_533,q_auto,c_fill/br-img-slides/004/431/800/ca7761a4360ae26cb69ee014607228b7_crop_exact.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="card-right">
        <form action="">
          <div class="name">
            <label for="name" placeholder='Name'>Name</label>
            <input type="text" id='name' required>
          </div>
          <div class="seat">
            <label for="seat">Select your seat</label>
            <select name="seat" id="seat">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>

          </div>
          <div class="handicapped">
            <label for="handicap">Handicapped?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='Handicapped'>
          </div>
          <div class="wrestler">
            <label for="wrestler">Select for favorite superstar</label>
            <select name="wrestler" id="wrestler">
              <option value="asaka">Asaka</option>
              <option value="mcintyre">Drew Mcintyre</option>
              <option value="zayne">Sami Zayne</option>
              <option value="reigns">Roman Reigns</option>
              <option value="flair">Charlotte Flair</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="submit">
            <button>Sign Up!</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v796tdsL/6/).

Comment: Thank you. I was overlooking the fact that I could select elements within another element vis .className element{

Answer (score 0):

```
.card-right div {
    padding: 0 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.